# My function doesn't run on button click (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm a noob in javascript and I'm really having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my code. The `submitPledge` function doesn't work at all when I click a button which it should. PLS HELP!!!

```js
// validate pledge
function validate() {
  let pledge2 = document.getElementById("pledge2").value;
  let pledge3 = document.getElementById("pledge3").value;

  if (pledge2 == null || pledge2 < 25) {
    alert("Pledge must be $25 or higher");
    return false;
  }
  if (pledge3 == null || pledge3 < 75) {
    alert("Pledge must be $75 or higher");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
// submit pledge
function submitPledge(e) {
  if (validate() == true) {
    if (e.target.id == "pledge1submit") {
      // let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      // backers++;
      // updateStats(added, backers);
      alert("working");
    }

    if (e.target.id == "pledge2submit") {
      let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      backers++;
      let remains = document.querySelector(".101left");
      remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
      updateStats(added, backers);
    }
    if (e.target.id == "pledge3submit") {
      let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      backers++;
      let remains = document.querySelector(".64left");
      remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
      updateStats(added, backers);
    }

    modalContainer.style.display = "none";
    modalSuccess.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    alert("Not working!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pledge" id="no-reward-pledge">
  <p>Enter your pledge</p>
  <div class="pledge-right">
    <label class="input-amt" for="pledge1">$<input
        type="number"
        name="pledge"
        id="pledge1"
        min="1"
        value="1"
    /></label>
    <div class="btn continue" id="pledge1submit" onclick="submitPledge(this)">
      Continue
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have updated my code and this is what works:

```
//Submit pledge
for (i = 0; i < continueBtns.length; i++) {
  continueBtns[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (validate(true)) {
      if (e.target.id == "pledge1submit") {
        let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
        backers++;
        updateStats(added, backers);
      }

      if (e.target.id == "pledge2submit") {
        let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
        backers++;
        let remains = document.getElementsByClassName("101left");
        // remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < remains.length; i++) {
          remains[i].innerHTML = Number(remains[i].innerHTML) - 1;
        }
        updateStats(added, backers);
      }
      if (e.target.id == "pledge3submit") {
        let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
        backers++;
        let remains = document.getElementsByClassName("64left");
        // remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < remains.length; i++) {
          remains[i].innerHTML = Number(remains[i].innerHTML) - 1;
        }
        updateStats(added, backers);
      }

      modalContainer.style.display = "none";
      modalSuccess.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      alert("Not working!");
    }
  });
}
```

However, referencing the functon like `for (i = 0; i < continueBtns.length; i++) { continueBtns[i].addEventListener("click", submitPledge)` does not work even if I pass `submitPledge(e)`. The object (e) doesn't get read.

Comment: Hi, show me your html code.

Comment: Which is the error?

Comment: @MohammadMohammadi Sorry for the delay in response. I had an exam. I've added the html, pls have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm really not sure. I don't get any errors in the javascript code.

Comment: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"_

Comment: FYI: value is never going to be null. And value is a string, not a number.

Comment: Your error states that it can not find the element. So you are referencing an element that does not have the id you said it does. OR you are not referencing a child element correctly. Hard to help since the HTML is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

You access the `value` attribute in `validate()` before you check the element for `null`. Therefor you get the `TypeError`.

Move the attribute access `.value` into the `if` and it works.

```js
// validate pledge
function validate() {
  let pledge2 = document.getElementById("pledge2");
  let pledge3 = document.getElementById("pledge3");

  if (pledge2 == null || pledge2.value < 25) {
    alert("Pledge must be $25 or higher");
    return false;
  }
  if (pledge3 == null || pledge3.value < 75) {
    alert("Pledge must be $75 or higher");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
// submit pledge
function submitPledge(e) {
  if (validate() == true) {
    if (e.target.id == "pledge1submit") {
      // let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      // backers++;
      // updateStats(added, backers);
      alert("working");
    }

    if (e.target.id == "pledge2submit") {
      let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      backers++;
      let remains = document.querySelector(".101left");
      remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
      updateStats(added, backers);
    }
    if (e.target.id == "pledge3submit") {
      let added = e.target.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1].value;
      backers++;
      let remains = document.querySelector(".64left");
      remains.innerHTML = Number(remains) - 1;
      updateStats(added, backers);
    }

    modalContainer.style.display = "none";
    modalSuccess.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    alert("Not working!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pledge" id="no-reward-pledge">
  <p>Enter your pledge</p>
  <div class="pledge-right">
    <label class="input-amt" for="pledge1">$<input
        type="number"
        name="pledge"
        id="pledge1"
        min="1"
        value="1"
    /></label>
    <div class="btn continue" id="pledge1submit" onclick="submitPledge(this)">
      Continue
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you return false in function, i think you must return your Func my friend:
and must pass event not this:

```
<div class="btn continue" id="pledge1submit" onclick="return submitPledge(event)">
```